# Можно ли в Android поднять тон звука?

Tags: java, android, аудио

Подскажите, можно ли в Android поднять тон звука? Например у меня есть нота До и мне нужно поднять её тон чтобы получить ноту Ре и тд. Есть ли в Android такая возможность? Если есть то как этого можно добиться?

Answer (score 0):

Звук можно генерировать следующим кодом

```
ToneGenerator toneG = new ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, 255);
toneG.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_SUP_ERROR, 500); //500 is duration in ms }
```

По звучанию не скажу, слух не очень.

ToneGenerator имеет много поднастроек, кроме TONE_SUP_ERROR

Comment: спасибо за информацию)